# Ruby string initialized with nil causes exception

Tags: ruby, string, constructor

Why does a Ruby String initialized with `nil` cause this exception?

```
irb(main):001:0> String.new(nil)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
        from (irb):1:in `initialize'
        from (irb):1:in `new'
        from (irb):1
        from /Users/jord/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

I would expect this to work, but return an empty string.

Is this correct behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.new` takes as an argument what the content of the new string should be. `nil` cannot be the content of a string. If you want to get an empty string in this way, you need to do `String.new("")`. `nil` is not `""`.

Or, maybe you expected it to return the empty string because `String.new` (without an argument) does. If this is the case, then you are confusing "absence of an argument" and "`nil` argument". They are different. In fact, suppose you define a method `foo`:

```
def foo *args
  args
end
```

If you call `foo` without any argument, then `args` inside the method call would be `[]`, whereas if you call `foo(nil)`, then `args` would be `[nil]`.

```
foo      # => []
foo(nil) # => [nil]
```

This tells us that "absence of an argument" and "`nil` argument" are different.

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't typically instantiate strings using .new, if you do, it requires an actual string.

For example:

```
String.new('hello')
```